# Ternary: TernaryListPlot and DiscretizeRegion - Formatting and Error Messages

Tags: plotting, discretization

I am trying to illustrate regions based on conditions in a ternary. I got help with a ternary template and I would like to include the regions now.

- Template

  ```
    Clear[A, B, F, ternary, reg, sol, reg2, sol2, tern]
    F = {1, 0, 0};
    B = {0, 1, 0};
    A = {0, 0, 1};
    TernaryListPlot[{{A -> ""}, {B -> ""}, {F -> ""}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Blue}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14], 
     GridLines -> True, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
     FrameTicks -> Range[0, 1, .2], 
     Prolog -> {{Black, Thick, Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}}]}, 
    {Black, Thick, Line[{{0.5, 0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, 
    {Black, Thick, Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, 
    {Text[Style["A", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 0, 1}, {3, 1}]}, 
    {Text[Style["B", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {1, 0, 0}, {-3, 1}]}, 
    {Text[Style["C", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 1, 0}, {0, -4}]}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0.2]
  ```

[image]

- Regions/Conditions

  ```
    ternary[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] = {p1 + 1/2 p2, Sqrt[3]/2 p2};
    reg[a_, b_] := ImplicitRegion[{a*x + b*z >= 0.5, {x, y, z} >= 0, x + y + z == 1}, {x, y, z}];
    sol[a_, b_] := {x, y, z} /. FindInstance[{x, y, z} \[Element] reg[a, b], {x, y, z}, 1];
    reg2[c_] := ImplicitRegion[{c*y >= 0.25, {x, y, z} >= 0, x + y + z == 1}, {x, y, z}];
    sol2[c_] := {x, y, z} /. FindInstance[{x, y, z} \[Element] reg2[c], {x, y, z}, 1];
    tern[a_, b_, c_] := TernaryListPlot[sol[a, b], 
    Prolog -> {{Blue,DiscretizeRegion[TransformedRegion[reg[a, b], ternary], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/100000]}, 
    {Red, DiscretizeRegion[TransformedRegion[reg2[c], ternary], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/100000]}},         
    PlotStyle -> Transparent]
    tern[0.51, 0.5, 0.6]
  ```

[image]

*** Question 1**

Where do I place the template and/or graph when combining both?

*** Question 2**

How do I avoid the error messages "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region 
ParametricRegion[<<2>>]" when a<=0.5 and b<=0.5 and get a blank ternary indicating no solution?

Thank you!

Comment: If you name the first TernaryListPlot in the template pl1 i.e. pl1=TernaryListPlot[{{A -> ""}, {B -> ""}, {F -> ""}},...,PlotRangePadding -> 0.2] and then do Show[{tern[0.51, 0.5, 0.6], pl1}], is this what you want? Also, for your Question 2, I do not get any error messages.

Comment: The error message appears if used for example tern[0.25,0.25,0.6].

Comment: It only provides the grid lines and the corner points - but no corner labels and no black triangle. The formatting follows the second triangle/output/picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When `a=0.25,b=0.25,c=0.6`, some region is `EmptyRegion[3]`, so `DiscretizeRegion` gave warning message.
- Here we also recommend to directly use `Simplex` and `HalfSpace`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg1[a_, b_] = 
  RegionIntersection[Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]], 
   HalfSpace[-{a, 0, b}, -.5]];
polys1[a_, b_] := 
  If[reg1[a, b] === EmptyRegion[3], Nothing, 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg1[a, b]], 2]];
reg2[c_] = 
  RegionIntersection[Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]], 
   HalfSpace[-{0, c, 0}, -.25]];
polys2[c_] := 
  If[reg2[c] === EmptyRegion[3], Nothing, 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg2[c]], 2]];
tern[a_, b_, c_] := 
 TernaryListPlot[{}, 
  Prolog -> {{Blue, polys1[a, b]}, {Red, polys2[c]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Transparent]
Manipulate[tern[a, b, .5], {{a, .25}, 0.1, 1}, {{b, .25}, .1, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

- To combine the two figures, we can add all of them to `Prolog` or `Epilog`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg1[a_, b_] = 
  RegionIntersection[Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]], 
   HalfSpace[-{a, 0, b}, -.5]];
polys1[a_, b_] := 
  If[reg1[a, b] === EmptyRegion[3], Nothing, 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg1[a, b]], 2]];
reg2[c_] = 
  RegionIntersection[Simplex[IdentityMatrix[3]], 
   HalfSpace[-{0, c, 0}, -.25]];
polys2[c_] := 
  If[reg2[c] === EmptyRegion[3], Nothing, 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg2[c]], 2]];
F = {1, 0, 0};
B = {0, 1, 0};
A = {0, 0, 1};
ternaryplot[a_, b_, c_] := 
  TernaryListPlot[{{A -> ""}, {B -> ""}, {F -> ""}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Blue}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 
    Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14], 
   GridLines -> True, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   FrameTicks -> Range[0, 1, .2], 
   Prolog -> {{Blue, polys1[a, b]}, {Red, polys2[c]}}, 
   Epilog -> {{Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0.5, 0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Text[
       Style["A", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 0, 1}, {3, 1}]}, {Text[
       Style["B", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {1, 0, 0}, {-3, 1}]}, {Text[
       Style["C", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 1, 0}, {0, -4}]}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0.2];
ternaryplot[.81, .5, .6]
```

- 

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg1[a_, b_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
     a*x + b*(1 - x - y) >= 0.5 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
      1}}] // DiscretizeRegion;
reg2[c_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
     c*y >= 0.25 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
F = {1, 0, 0};
B = {0, 1, 0};
A = {0, 0, 1};
ternaryplot[a_, b_, c_] := 
  TernaryListPlot[{{A -> ""}, {B -> ""}, {F -> ""}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Blue}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 
    Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14], 
   GridLines -> True, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   FrameTicks -> Range[0, 1, .2], 
   Prolog -> {{Blue, reg1[a, b]}, {Red, reg2[c]}}, 
   Epilog -> {{Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0.5, 0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Text[
       Style["A", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 0, 1}, {3, 1}]}, {Text[
       Style["B", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {1, 0, 0}, {-3, 1}]}, {Text[
       Style["C", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 1, 0}, {0, -4}]}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0.2];
ternaryplot[.81, .5, .6]
```

[image]

Comment: `reg[a_, b_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
     a*x + b*(1 - x - y) >= 0.5 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
      1}}] // DiscretizeRegion;
reg2[c_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
     c*y >= 0.25 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
tern[a_, b_, c_] := 
 TernaryListPlot[{}, Prolog -> {{Blue, reg[a, b]}, {Red, reg2[c]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Transparent]
tern[0.51, 0.5, 0.6]`

Comment: Thank you! Depending on the two approaches - simplex/halfspace vs. conditions (comment) - the black triangle is on top (picture) or below the blue/red area.

reg[a_, b_] := 
 ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
    a*x + b*(1 - x - y) >= 0.5 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
     1}}] // DiscretizeRegion; 
reg[c_] := 
 ParametricRegion[{{x + y/2, (Sqrt[3] y)/2}, 
    c*y >= 0.25 && x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}] // 
  DiscretizeRegion;

Comment: tern[a_, b_, c_] := 
 TernaryListPlot[{{A -> ""}, {B -> ""}, {F -> ""}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Blue}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14],
   GridLines -> True, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  FrameTicks -> Range[0, 1, .2], 
  Epilog -> {{Blue, reg[a, b]}, {Red, reg[c]}},

Comment: Prolog -> {{Black, Thick, 
     Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
     Line[{{0.5, 0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Black, Thick, 
     Line[{{0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}]}, {Text[
      Style["A", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 0, 1}, {3, 1}]}, {Text[
      Style["B", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {1, 0, 0}, {-3, 1}]}, {Text[
      Style["C", 15, FontColor -> Blue], {0, 1, 0}, {0, -4}]}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.2]
tern[0.51, 0.5, 0.6]

Comment: I would prefer the second solution as it would allow me to expand the number of conditions - compared to the halfspace method.